# JavaScript, on "mouseover" a block appears and disappears when you try to move the mouse over it

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I need to hang a "mouseover" handler on 2 buttons.
It should work like this - you hover over one button - one block is displayed and you can hover over this block and it does not disappear until you remove the mouse from the button and from the block itself. If I hover over another block - the first block disappears and the second block is displayed and the same thing happens, as with the first button and block.

The result is needed, as on this site when you hover over the menu https://www.zoo-bio.co.uk/

Unfortunately, I did not find anything like this on the Internet, there is no one to ask, so I am writing here.

Here is my code:

```
// first button
const carBrandsFilterButton = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-brands-button');
// first hidden block
const carBrandsFilter = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-brands');

// second button
const carPartsFilterButton = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-parts-button');
// second hidden block
const carPartsFilter = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-parts');

// variable for setting timeout
let timeout;

// function when you are over the button
function over(carFilter, carFilterButton) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => carFilter.style.display = 'block', 400);
  carFilterButton.style.background = 'rgba(47, 59, 94, 0.9)';
}

// function when you are out of the button
function out(carFilter, carFilterButton) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  carFilter.style.display = 'none';
  carFilterButton.style.background = 'rgba(47, 59, 94)';
}

// first listener to handle the first button and his block
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  const filterField = e.target.parentNode.closest('.main-header__car-brands');
  if (e.target.dataset.brands === "brands" || filterField !== null) {
    over(carBrandsFilter, carBrandsFilterButton)
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'BODY' || filterField === null) {
    out(carBrandsFilter, carBrandsFilterButton);
  }
})

// second listener to handle the second button and his block
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  const filterField = e.target.parentNode.closest('.main-header__car-parts');
  if (e.target.dataset.parts === "parts" || filterField !== null) {
    over(carPartsFilter, carPartsFilterButton)
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'BODY' || filterField === null) {
    out(carPartsFilter, carPartsFilterButton);
  }
})
```

But it doesn't work fine, it looks like these 2 listeners are in conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The Zoo-Bio example you provided is done with JavaScript, but can easily be done with pure HTML and CSS.

It works because the `menu` is a child of the `menu-button` which allows you to hide the `menu` by default but display it on `menu-button` hover. The key is to position your `menu` element directly beside your `menu-button` so the mouse never leaves the element when navigating through the menu.

```css
ul.menu--list {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li.menu--button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.expand--menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 50vw;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

li.menu--button:hover > .expand--menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main menu--list">
  <li class="menu--button">
    Menu Button 1
    <div class="expand--menu one">
      <ul class="menu--list">
        <li class="menu--button">
          Submenu Button 1
          <div class="expand--menu two">A submenu</div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu--button">
          Submenu Button 2
          <div class="expand--menu two">Another submenu</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu--button">
    Menu Button 2
    <div class="expand--menu one">Menu 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content under the menu</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and solution to the problem.
I have already done this through css before, but this time the task was to do it through Javascript, and after the publication I sat here for another 2 hours and finally found a solution to the problem, if someone is interested, I don’t know how correct it is from a point in terms of code, I just started my way in programming, but here is a solution in javascript.

```
   // first button
const carBrandsFilterButton = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-brands-button');
// first hidden block
const carBrandsFilter = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-brands');

// second button
const carPartsFilterButton = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-parts-button');
// second hidden block
const carPartsFilter = document.querySelector('.main-header__car-parts');

// variable for setting timeout
let timeout;

// function when you are over the button
function over(carFilter, carFilterButton) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => carFilter.style.display = 'block', 400);
  carFilterButton.style.background = 'rgba(47, 59, 94, 0.9)';
}

// function when you are out of the button
function out(carFilter, carFilterButton) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  carFilter.style.display = 'none';
  carFilterButton.style.background = 'rgba(47, 59, 94)';
}

document.querySelector('.main-header__filter').addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {

  if (e.target.className === 'main-header__car-brands-button') {
    // first listener to handle the first button and his block
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      const filterField = e.target.parentNode.closest('.main-header__car-brands');
      if (e.target.dataset.brands === "brands" || filterField !== null) {
        over(carBrandsFilter, carBrandsFilterButton)
      } else {
        out(carBrandsFilter, carBrandsFilterButton);
      }
    })
  }

  if (e.target.className === 'main-header__car-parts-button') {
// second listener to handle the second button and his block
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      const filterField = e.target.parentNode.closest('.main-header__car-parts');
      if (e.target.dataset.parts === "parts" || filterField !== null) {
        over(carPartsFilter, carPartsFilterButton)
      } else {
        out(carPartsFilter, carPartsFilterButton);
      }
    })
  }

})
```